# How to read only new events added to the event log?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, event-log

I'm working on a project to read and display windows event logs. I have used the following code to read the events from the event log and display them.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EventLog[] ev;

    ev = EventLog.GetEventLogs();

    Console.WriteLine("Number of logs on computer: " + ev.Length);

    foreach (EventLog log in ev)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Log: " + log.Log);
        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entry: " + entry.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Source: " + entry.Source);
            Console.WriteLine("Category: " + entry.Category);
            Console.WriteLine("EventID: " + entry.Source);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine. It displays all the events that have been stored in the log files. But what I want to achieve after this is, I have to read the upcoming events and `update them every 10 seconds`.

If I just go on and call the same function again, I'll get all the events, but I only want the events that were added newly. How do I achieve this?

TL DR: I would like to listen to only newly added events in event log, not the whole event log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, by working through MSDN. This is for people who might come in the future here, [EntryWrittenEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.entrywritteneventhandler?view=netframework-4.7.2) is the solution.

Although the previous answer is correct I just wanted to add, you can add an event handler using [EventLogWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) for logs other than administrative logs.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
EventLog appLogs = new EventLog("Application");

var entries = appLogs.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
                     .Where(x => x.TimeWritten >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-60))
                     .ToList();
```

However, it wont matter what time you filter by it will still take the same amount of time.

There is no way i know of to speed this up (that i know of)

Though you might want to look into the [EventLog.EntryWritten Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Occurs when an entry is written to an event log on the local computer.
>
> **Remnarks**
>
> To get event notifications, you must set EnableRaisingEvents to true.
>   You can only receive event notifications when entries are written on
>   the local computer. You cannot receive notifications for entries
>   written on remote computers.

```
EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog("Application", ".", "testEventLogEvent");                 

myNewLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(MyOnEntryWritten);
myNewLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Presumably this will be a lighter way than trying to poll the EventLog Plumbing

Comment: thanks for the solution @TheGeneral , It'd really be great if there was something like an event collector which collects the events directly, rather than reading them from an event log!